# Android how to detect resume/recovery from a crash in activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making some intializations in my main activity.
When a crash happens deep in the application, the application restarts to the last active activity, but I loose some of the information that was set during the main activity.
I would like to know whether an activity had resumed from a crash and then set the missing info.
Is this information available from an intent ?
(I know I should take care of the crash, but it still interests me...)
If it is not possible, is there a way to start a fresh application instead, (run main activity) after a crash ?

Comment: There is a third party lib named "acra", I have used that allows you to send the crash report to your own server when it happenes.
MAy be it provides some more customizations to accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: I read about it and didn't find a 'clean' way... I am looking for something more straight-forward like detect the recovery from crash on "onResume".